# My cookies are not being set after the login form has been sent

Tags: php, ajax, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a login script and a functions.php script to check if the session username and cookie are set. When the user logs in, if they select the remember me, the cookie is supposed to set. But the problem is that, the script works, but the cookie doesn't set so the user is not being logged in. I've searched through so many topics on here and tried as many solutions as possible, but I still either get the same result or end up giving me more errors.

> ```
>                           if (isset($_POST['rem']) && $_POST['rem'] == 'on') > {
>                               setcookie('MCLatestUser', $token, 31622400, > '/');
>                                 session_regenerate_id(true);
>                             }
> ```
>
> This is the part of the code that should set the cookie if remember is checked.

Log.php (Since I use an ajax login script, the url is set to this):

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
error_reporting(-1);

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    try {
        $check = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
        $res = mysqli_num_rows($check);
        if($res > 0) {
            while($run = mysqli_fetch_array($check, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $blocked = $run['blocked'];
                $deactivated = $run['deactivated'];
                $paused = $run['paused'];
                $verified = $run['verified'];
                $rank = $run['rank'];
                $token = $run['token'];
                $pass = $run['password'];
                $pbackup = $run['pbackup'];
                if($verified == 'true') {
                    if($blocked == 'true') {
                        echo 'Looks like your account was blocked. If you think this is an error, please contact an admin via support@mclatest.com';
                    } else if($deactivated == 'true') {
                        echo 'Looks like your account has been deactivated. If you think this is an error, please contact an admin via support@mclatest.com';
                    } else if($paused == 'true') {
                        echo 'Looks like your account is frozen. If you think this is an error, please contact an admin via support@mclatest.com';
                    } else {
                        if(password_verify($password, $pass)) {
                            $timestamp = time();
                            // Authenticated, set session variables
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $run['username'];
                            if (isset($_POST['rem']) && $_POST['rem'] == 'on') {
                                setcookie('MCLatestUser', $token, 31622400, '/');
                                session_regenerate_id(true);
                            }
                            $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE users SET Ip = '$ipaddress', login_ip = '$ipaddress', latest_login_date = '$now', login_date = '$date', login_time = '$time', login_day = '$day', login_month = '$month', login_year = '$year', status = '$timestamp' WHERE email = '$email'");
                            if($sql) {
                                echo "Success!";
                            } else {
                                echo "Error login in";
                            }
                            // do stuffs
                        } else if(password_verify($password, $pbackup)) {
                            $timestamp = time();
                            // Authenticated, set session variables
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $run['username'];
                            if (isset($_POST['rem']) && $_POST['rem'] == 'on') {
                                setcookie('MCLatestUser', $token, 31622400, '/');
                                session_regenerate_id(true);
                            }
                            $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE users SET Ip = '$ipaddress', login_ip = '$ipaddress', latest_login_date = '$now', login_date = '$date', login_time = '$time', login_day = '$day', login_month = '$month', login_year = '$year', status = '$timestamp' WHERE email = '$email'");
                            if($sql) {
                                echo "Success!";
                            } else {
                                echo "Error login in";
                            }
                            // do stuffs
                        } else {
                            echo "<h4 style='font-weight:bold;font-family:arial;margin:8px'>Your password is incorrect, please try again. If you still get this error after using your backup password, please <a href='https://mclatest.com/community/reset.php?r=password'>reset</a> your password</h4>";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<h4 style='font-weight:bold;font-family:arial;margin:8px'>You need to verify your account. Please click this link to <a href='https://mclatest.com/community/confirm.php?email=".$email."&token=".$token."'>verify your account</a></h4>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No records of that user have been found!';
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

} else {
    echo "Invalid email";
}
```

Login.php (the html and ajax form):

```
<form id="login_form" style="text-align:center" method="post">
                                <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $("#login").click(function(e) {
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                            var email = $("#email").val();
                                            if (email = "") {
                                                $("#error_msg").html("<h4>Email cannot be empty</h4>");
                                            } else {
                                                var data = $("#login_form").serialize();
                                                $.ajax({
                                                    type: "POST",
                                                    url: "../inc/log.php",
                                                    data: data,
                                                    beforeSend: function() {
                                                        $("#error_msg").fadeOut();
                                                        $("#login").val('sending ...');
                                                    },
                                                    success: function(data) {
                                                        if (data == "Success!") {
                                                            // alert("Works"); //for testing purposes
                                                            window.location.href = "index.php";
                                                        } else {
                                                            $("#error_msg").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                                                                $("#error_msg").html('<div style="border:1px solid: red; background:rgba(255,0,0,0.9;)">'+data+'!</div>');
                                                                $("#login").val('Login');
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    error: function(data) {
                                                        alert("Process Failed!");
                                                    }
                                                });
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label ">
                                    <label for="input_email" class="mdl-textfield__label">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="mdl-textfield__input" maxlength="255" id="input_email" />
                                </div>
                                <br>

                                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                                    <label for="input_password" class="mdl-textfield__label">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="mdl-textfield__input" maxlength="255" id="input_password" />
                                </div>
                                <br>

                                <label style="width:auto !important" for="remember_me" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
                                    <input name="rem" type="checkbox" id="remember_me" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked />
                                    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Stay logged in?</span>
                                </label>
                                <br>

                                <nav style="width:auto !important;display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-pack:center" class="mdl-navigation">
                                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="forgot.php?ftype=password">Forgot Password?</a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
                                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="register.php">Register?</a>
                                </nav>
                                <br>

                                <input type="submit" id="login" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect" name="login" value="Login"/>
                            </form>
```

functions.php (this is the portion of the script to check the session and cookie variables):

```
function loggedIn() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['MCLatestUser'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Script works but cookies aren't being sent. I'm at my wits end here, been working on this for over 4-5 hours now, had over 35 chrome tabs open just to figure this out. I am probably overlooking a minor detail. [Login Page Link](https://mclatest.com/community/login.php)

It works if i remove the `&& $_COOKIE['MCLatestUser']` from the function script

Comment: Before looking at it in detail I suppose we should get the obvious out the way first... are cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yes, the default PHPSESSID cookie is always set aswell

Comment: Don't put resolved in the title, just accept an answer instead.

Comment: I have to wait a day, I tried the first time I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie('MCLatestUser', $token, 31622400, '/');
```

This method has some problems in the third parameter.It should be based on the current time.

[PHP: setcookie - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: sorry, it didn't change anything

Comment: It's great to figured it out.But I doubt whether that script can run.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out it was the browser's fault. I tried it on Microsoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox and it worked. So I looked about for that issue and all I had to do was `clear my cookies and site data` on chrome. Thank you to those who helped and those who wanted to but couldn't/didn't.

Comment: I'd recommend editing the question to make it clear that it is resolved. That would help anyone finding this page via a Google search as it would save them time reading through looking for a solution

Comment: Thanks, I have added "(RESOLVED)" to the question, not sure if that was what you meant though.